# How to edit my question on RBF kernel in Python so that it gets reopened?

Tags: discussion, questions, reopen-closed

Can someone advise on how to rephrase this question to be acceptable?

[How to tune `gamma` parameter of precomputed RBF kernel in Python using `gridsearchCV` and `pipeline`?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357700/how-to-tune-gamma-parameter-of-precomputed-rbf-kernel-in-python-using-gridsea)

Comment: I'd go straight to Stack Overflow (SO) on this. I don't use your software but the question looks in fine shape for anyone who does, as it seems to have a dataset all included. It's a model question for SO, but _ipso facto_ utterly off-topic here. There is no saving that by tweaking the question.

Comment: Furthermore the tag "bug" is referred to situations in which the stackexchange homepage is not working properly. I replaced it with the tag "discussion".

Answer (score 7):

The question you linked seems to be primarily about Coding and not about statistics.

You focus too much on the python/SVC code. If you want this question to be reopened you should make clear why your question relates primarily to the computation of the kernel and not to the python code.

Comment: +1.  Additionally, the question as stated--"I would appreciate any advice"--is far too unfocused for any SE site.  Great information on asking on-topic questions that will be answered is available at http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#forum.